# SfDoctrineGuard Permission

Tags: symfony1

I use SfDoctrine guard in my test project. I use also SfForkedApply for registration and managing accounts. I set 3 type permissions: "user","creator","administrator".
My question is : When i Create account whit sfForkedApply , How to set automaticly "User" permission to this new user .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know your exact details, but your would  probably need to override the `doSave` method of the 'user register' form and set the user permission.

Answer (score 0):

Vlad you help me very much :) In doSave i added 4 rows and evriting is ok :) this is the code. It work :)

```
 public function doSave($con = null)
    {
        $user = new sfGuardUser();
        $user->setUsername($this->getValue('username'));
        $user->setPassword($this->getValue('password'));
        $user->setEmailAddress( $this->getValue('email') );
        // They must confirm their account first
        $user->setIsActive(false);
        $user->save();
        $this->getObject()->setUserId($user->getId());

        //THIS LINE I ADDED 
        $permission = new sfGuardUserPermission();
        $permission->setPermissionId('1');
        $permission->setUserId($user->getId());
        $permission->save();
        return parent::doSave($con);
    }
```